# Automatic reduce/combine categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset (more than 100k rows) with around 9k categories that looks like this:

| Category | Feature |
| --- | --- |
| ABC-XYZ-123-!@! | Cell 2 |
| ABC-XYZ-2@# | Cell 4 |
| ABC-XYZ | Cell 4 |
| dfg-ZZZ-123-!@! | Cell 2 |
| dfg-ZZZ-2@# | Cell 4 |
| ABC-XYZ | Cell 4 |

Some rows have two levels (i.e. ABC-XYZ), three levels (i.e. ABC-XYZ-123), etc..

I'd like to reduce the number of categories to only 2 levels (i.e. XXX-XXX). Any ideia of how to do it in python?

Tks!!

I sincerely have no idea of where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by reduce the number of categories to two levels? Do you want to go from `ABC-XYZ-123-!@!` to `ABC-XYZ` or remove everything that does not have two levels

Comment: First option. Go from ABC-XYZ-123-!@! to ABC-XYZ.

Comment: In other words, I want to reduce the number of levels to just two. It doesn't matter what is after the first two levels ABC-XYZ

Comment: You can try something like `df['Category'].str.split('-', 2).agg(lambda x: '-'.join(x[:2]))` but the lambda function might be a little slow.

Comment: I solved this by spliting into columns:

df = survey['Department'].str.split('-', expand=True)

and concatenating:

df = df[0] + "-" + df[1] + "-" + df[2]

Tks!